# Import/Export of Hazelcast management Center configurations

Tags: hazelcast

We are running the Hazelcast management center inside a docker container running on an EC2 instance. We bring up/down the instances quite often. We are losing all the configurations(license/smtp/alerts) in this process.

1. Is there a way to export/import the current configurations in the management center?
2. Is there a way we can pass the startup configurations when bringing up the management center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a volume mount and specify an alternative configuration path using the system property `-Dhazelcast.mancenter.home=/path/to/volumemount`

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.6/manual/html-single/index.html#getting-started-to-management-center <- last sentence of that section below all the images ;)

Comment: Thanks Chris. This is exactly what I was looking for.